# Array of Generic Class Objects C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, generics, queue

I have a  generic class `Queue` that contains a template `Ttype2` as the placement holder for the type of data that will be stored in the information field of each node.
 In my driver class I want to instantiate an array of `Queue` class objects but I can't seem to figure it out. How might I go about doing this?

These didn't work but illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
// Queue Complex[] = new Queue();//invalid use of template name without identifier list
 //Queue<Ttype2> Complex[]; //template arg 1 is invalid
// vector<Queue> Complex2[];//invalid template arguments`
```

Queue Class declaration and constructor inside Queue.h header:

```
template <typename Ttype2>
class Queue
{
  // Global Data Items
  protected:
  Node <Ttype2> Front, Rear;
  int Length;

  // member function prototypes
  public:
  Queue();
  void AddRear(Node <Ttype2> ThisNode);
  Node <Ttype2> RemoveFront();
  void Modify(int Position, Node <Ttype2> ThisNode);
  void ClearAll();
  int GetSize();`
  Node <Ttype2> GetNode(int Position);
  Node <Ttype2>* toArray();
};`

// Constructor
template <typename Ttype2>
Queue <Ttype2> :: Queue()
{
  Rear = Front = NULL;
  Length = 0;
} // End of Constructor
`
```

Comment: Do I need to implement a generic array class to hold these generic objects?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Queue<int> *Complex = new Queue<int>();
Queue<int> Complex[1];
vector<Queue<int>> Complex2[1];
```

You need to give real params to your template when instantiating it.

```
Queue<Ttype2> // Ttype2 isn't a real type, use int, char, ...
```

---

Also you need to define your type `Node<>`. And if your want to assign `NULL` to `Rear` and `Front` it, first consider to make them pointers, second use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I will add to Yola's solution that if I want to keep many different `Queue<XXX>` in a single array,
I usually create an interface class `Queue_base`.

```
class Queue_base{
    public: virtual void func()=0;
};

template <typename Ttype2>class Queue : public Queue_base{
    public: void func(){
        //... some code
    }
};

int main() {
    Queue_base* complex[2];
    complex[0]=new Queue<int>();
    complex[1]=new Queue<float>();
    complex[0]->func(); 
    std::vector<Queue_base*> complex2;
    complex2.push_back(new Queue<char>());
    Queue<int>* c1=static_cast<Queue<int>*>(complex[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is live [demo](http://ideone.com/7aUA83).
Note that using virtual function reduces performance a bit.

It will also lose the type (reduce to `Queue_base*`) and restrict some function calling, but it is useful for some real-world cases.

To extend its usage `Node<T>` can also inherit from a new class `Node_Base` that has all common function of `Node<T>`, e.g. :-

```
template <typename Ttype2> class Queue : public Queue_Base{
  // Global Data Items
  protected:
  Node_Base* Front; //Front = new Node<Ttype2>();
  Node_Base* Rear;
```

It depends on your demand though.